# How to implement NFC example?

Tags: android, nfc

I am new to Android, and I want to develop an application related to NFC.

What resources are there available to help me develop android applications that use NFC?

Answer (score 2):

Look [android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com). A sample [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NFCDemo/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Study http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html and they also have a sample application.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented an [NFC Eclipse Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) which might get you started quickly. You will need an Android NFC-enabled 4.0 phone or an NFC reader and some tags to take full advantage of the plugin.